# Why does the '<<' operator sometimes behave differently in Javascript and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, bit-shift

Take the following code snippet:

```
<script>
var x = 25;
document.write(x << 9);
</script>

<?php
$x = 25;
echo ($x << 9);
?>
```

This outputs: `12800 12800`
OK. Normal so far... Now lets try this:

```
<script>
var x = 12345678;
document.write(x << 9);
</script>

<?php
$x = 12345678;
echo ($x << 9);
?>
```

This time the output is `2026019840 6320987136`

Why are the latter two values different? And, most importantly (to me), how do I get the PHP implementation to do what the Javascript implementation does? In other words, I want my PHP code to output 2026019840 instead of 6320987136

Comment: they're different because PHP is automatically converting to a long, as Python does. javascript instead gives you the low 32 bits.

Comment: splendid! So if I just & the value with 0xFFFFFFFF I get the desired value in PHP. Could you please submit that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `(x << 9) % 0x100000000` or its PHP equivalent. (or what you just said)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is giving you a 64 bit result.  Javascript is just giving you the lower 32bits.  If you use `(x << 9) & 0xFFFFFFFF` in PHP you'll get the low 32 bits.

you may run into problems with the sign bit though.  Try `(23456789 << 9)`